# detect jquery mouse move more frequently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on making a div that a person can draw in. I've utilized the `mousedown/mouseup/mousemove` events in jQuery. But the issue is, the mouse move event is firing too slow. When I try drawing I don't get connected lines, but scattered dots.

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zose3417/2/

is it possible to get this event to fire more frequently?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isPerformingLeftMouseClick = false;
    $('#sketch-box').on('mousedown', function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
                isPerformingLeftMouseClick = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                //('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
                break;
            case 3:
                //alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
                break;
            default:
                //alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
        }
    });
    $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
        isPerformingLeftMouseClick = false;
    });
    $('#sketch-box').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (isPerformingLeftMouseClick) {
            //var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
           var offset = $(this).offset();
           var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
           var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
            var linkDot = $('#dot-box').children().first().clone();
            $(linkDot).css('top', relY);
            $(linkDot).css('left', relX);
            $(this).append(linkDot);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No. You have to draw a line between the current and last known mouse positions, not just draw a dot at each position. This isn't an issue with jQuery, it's just the way the mouse move event works.

Comment: @nnnnnn mmm.. interesting. That's not good, the faster someone draws, the less fluid the lines will look. more research time

Comment: If there was a mouse event for literally every pixel the mouse passed over there could potentially be several thousand mouse move events per second. So people using drawing apps learn not to move the mouse too quickly. This is the case with non-browser drawing apps too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to increase the mousemove frequency, it's just based on what the browser can allow. This makes sense given the JavaScript eventloop and the different systems you run on. If you do a `setTimeout(500, ..)`, you might not actually get called until 510, 520, or longer if something is hogging the loop.

The best way to get the result you want is either by drawing lines between events (so saving the previous point and continuing it) or you can use interpolation to try to "guess" a better motion. Things like D3 will [help you do things like interpolation pretty easily](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js).

Edit: 
A neat way of doing this, may be to continue drawing your dots just-in-time as the browser allows, and then interpolating the set of dots for that motion as you go.